# Unable to start mysqld

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run mysqld from command line, I get the following error:

```
2015-08-14 18:56:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-14 18:56:59 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld (mysqld 5.6.26) starting as process 32 ...
2015-08-14 18:56:59 32 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Home.lower-test
2015-08-14 18:56:59 32 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Home.lower-test
```

Further, I found this error log in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data`:

```
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 18:41:53 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.26 started; log sequence number 1625977
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: de2e6b40-41bc-11e5-ba30-00270e1e8d17.
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-08-13 18:41:54 5104 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625977 and 1625977 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1625987 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.26 started; log sequence number 1625987
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-08-13 18:43:07 5636 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Too many arguments (first extra is 'performance_schema').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Binlog end
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-08-13 18:48:45 3692 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 18:53:18 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2015-08-13 18:53:19 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1625977
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.26 started; log sequence number 1626124
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-13 18:53:20 3304 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.26'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

But I am able to run mysqld as Administrator with no such errors.
Help me please as I'm new to MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` needs to be writable by your Windows user account.   Apparently it isn't.   There are three solutions:

1. Make yourself a local administrator on the box.   For developers, this is usually  desirable anyway.
2. Log in as administrator, travel to the parent of the above directory, right click, and select "Properties".   From there, select the "Security" tab, and grant full control of the directory to your username.
3. Run mysqld as a service, owned by the Administrator account.   Instructions to do so are in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped :)